# Rendering key value in vue list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to render key value in the component when passing it in the list?

I have data in this form:

```
      { id: 1,  title: "test", text: "Lorem ipsum doloret imes", date: "20-01-2020" },
      { id: 2,  title: "tes", text: "Lorem ipsum doloret imes", date: "20-01-2020" },
      { id: 3,  title: "est", text: "Lorem ipsum doloret imes", date: "20-01-2020" },
```

I would like to display id in the child comopnent:

```
 <single-news-template v-for="m in data"
                v-bind:key="m.id"
                v-bind:title="m.title"
                v-bind:text="m.text"
                v-bind:date="m.date">
                </single-news-template>
```

Here is the component

```
<v-list-item dense
                >

            <v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-avatar color="indigo" size="36">
            <span class="white--text headline">{{key}}</span>
            </v-avatar>
                </v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title><a href="">{{title}}</a></v-list-item-title>
                    <v-list-item-subtitle>[...]{{text}}[...]</v-list-item-subtitle>
                    <v-list-item-subtitle>{{date}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
                </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>



<script>
    export default {
        name: "SingleNewsTemplate",
        props: ["key","title", "text", "date"]
    }
</script>
```

However the key is not rendered in the avatar item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either name it to something else since `key` is reserved (for example, `id`)

```
<single-news-template v-for="m in data"
  v-bind:key="m.id"
  v-bind:id="m.id"
  v-bind:title="m.title"
  v-bind:text="m.text"
  v-bind:date="m.date">
</single-news-template>
```

Or use `$vnode.key` instead.

```
<span class="white--text headline">{{$vnode.key}}</span>
```

Comment: But id needs to be assigned as key in vue list loop as far as I understand, so how can I render id while also assigning it to key?

Comment: @AlexT You can retain `v-bind:key="m.id"` and add `v-bind:id="m.id"`. You can then use the `id` prop.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the `key` attribute is a special attribute of Vue itself. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key or https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State for more informations.

Instead of using `:key` you have to use another property name like `:id`.

```html
<single-news-template v-for="m in data"
  :key="m.id"
  :id="m.id"
  :title="m.title"
  :text="m.text"
  :date="m.date"></single-news-template>
```

And in your component you use the property `id` instead of `key`.

Comment: So how can I render it then?

Comment: So can I bind `id` twice? Once as a key and once as `:id` ? `v-bind:key="m.id"` `v-bind:id="m.id"`

Comment: Yes you can. Try it out 